# Create duplicate rows based on the values in an array in a cell of the actual row

Tags: python, r, excel, excel-formula, data-cleaning

I have a dataset and each row has a cell with an array of elements. I want to break that array into separate elements and duplicate the rows as many times as the array length and fill the array elements in place of the array one by one.

What I have:

| example column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| name 1 | ["A", "B", "C"] |

What I want:

| example column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| name 1 | "A" |
| name 1 | "B" |
| name 1 | "C" |

**R or Python** code preferred but Excel would work too

Comment: In R you can use dplyr::unnest

Comment: You should look at `?stack`

Comment: I think Ric means `tidyr::unnest`, as in `your_data |> unnest(Column_B)`. That will work fine if it's a `list` column. If not you can use `jsonlite::fromJSON` to parse the JSON into a list column first, then unnest it.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow for this approach is as follows:

1. `str_replace_all()` from the `stringr` package to remove all special characters
2. `separate_wider_delim()` to separate each letter into separate columns
3. `pivot_longer()` to create rows for each value per group

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Example dataframe based on your example
df <- data.frame(colA = "name 1",
                 colB = "[\"A\", \"B\", \"C\"]")

df %>% 
  mutate(colB = str_replace_all(colB, "[[:punct:]]", "")) %>%
  separate_wider_delim(colB, 
                       " ", 
                       names = c(paste0("col", (1:3))),
                       too_few = "align_start") %>%
  pivot_longer(!colA, values_to = "colB") %>%
  select(-name)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
#  colA   colB
#  <chr>  <chr>
# 1 name 1 A    
# 2 name 1 B    
# 3 name 1 C 

# Example dataframe with varying list lengths (in case values in "colB" vary)
df <- data.frame(colA = c("name 1", "name 2"),
                 colB = c("[\"A\", \"B\", \"C\"]",
                          "[\"A\", \"B\", \"C\"], \"D\"]"))

df %>% 
  mutate(colB = str_replace_all(colB, "[[:punct:]]", "")) %>%
  separate_wider_delim(colB, 
                       " ", 
                       names = c(paste0("col", (1:4))),
                       too_few = "align_start") %>%
  pivot_longer(!colA, values_to = "colB") %>%
  filter(!is.na(colB)) %>%
  select(-name)
  
# A tibble: 7 × 2
#  colA   colB 
#  <chr>  <chr>
# 1 name 1 A    
# 2 name 1 B    
# 3 name 1 C    
# 4 name 2 A    
# 5 name 2 B    
# 6 name 2 C    
# 7 name 2 D
```

Note that `too_few = "align_start"` is for if your character lengths in "colB" vary. Also, you may need to edit `names = c(paste0("col", (1:n)))`, where n is the maximum length of the values in "colB".

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with `data.table`.

```
df = data.table(colA = "name 1",
                 colB = "[\"A\", \"B\", \"C\"]")

df[,.(colA, 
      colB = sapply(tstrsplit(gsub("[[:punct:]]","",colB)," "), `[` ))]
```

**output**

```
     colA   colB
   <char> <char>
1: name 1      A
2: name 1      B
3: name 1      C
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it wasn't preferred, but using formula in excel you could use:

```
=LET(string,  B1,
     clean,   MID(string,2,LEN(string)-2),
     split,   TEXTSPLIT(clean,,", "),
HSTACK( EXPAND(A1,
        ROWS(split),
        ,
        A1),
        split))
```

Where the string in `B1` is removed from the first and last character `[` and `]`.
And than split into an array of separate strings.

The value in A1 is expanded the number of times equal to the number of rows of the created array.

The two of these are stacked horizontally and together are the desired result.